# How do I access subscription data when using MonitoringMode.Sampling?

Tags: opc-ua, milo

I'm trying to find out how to use Eclipse Milo, and finding out how subscriptions go. I can easily get any MonitoringMode.Reporting mode subscription to work, but when I use Sampling it doesn't call the callback method (as expected). According to the docs it's supposed to "queue" up the values without calling the callback, but I can't find any place I can access that queue or anything similar. The UaMonitoredItem doesn't have anything in its interface that looks like it, neither does the request.

It's probably something obvious, but what am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered in the [GitHub repo discussions](https://github.com/eclipse/milo/discussions/872), but for posterity:

> MonitoringMode.Sampling simply means the server continues to sample the underlying but does not report the values to the client.
>
> The queued values are not available to you. If you change back to MonitoringMode.Reporting then they would be the first values reported for that item.